# Relation between the convergence of $\sum a_{n}$ and $\prod (1+a_{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, infinite-product

What is the relation between the convergence of $\sum a_{n}$ and $\prod (1+a_{n})$ where $a_{n} \in \mathbb{C} \ \forall n$ ?

Where can I find some references about this topic ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I believe their convergence is equivalent, by taking the logarithm of the product. I'll see around for references.

Comment: Surprisingly, not: see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/380180/17751).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, then $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n \text{ converges} \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log{a_n} \text{ converges}$$
Moreover, for $a_n \neq -1$, we have an equivalence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n) \text{ converges absolutely} \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \text{ converges absolutely}.$$
Thus, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ converges unconditionally.
Unfortunately, I have no reference for this in English language.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely true when $a_n$ are positive numbers as demonstrated [here](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/convergence-of-infinite-products/).

However, when $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$, then convergence of $\sum|a_n|$ is just a necessary condition for convergence of the infinite product.