# Let $a_k \geq 0$ be a sequence, then show that $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i < \infty$ implies $\prod_{i = 0}^\infty (1 + a_i) < \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I am trying to prove a claim:

> Let $a_i \geq 0$ be a sequence, then $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i < \infty$ implies $\prod_{i = 0}^\infty (1 + a_i) < \infty$

We can proceed by writing out the first few products...

$(1+a_0)(1+a_1) = (1 + a_0 + a_1 + a_0a_1)$

$(1+a_0)(1+a_1)(1+a_2)  = ((1 + a_0 + a_1) + a_0a_1)(1+a_2) =(1 + a_0 + a_1)(1+a_2) + a_0a_1 + a_0a_1a_2 = 1+a_0+a_1+a_2 + a_0a_2 + a_1a_2 + a_0 a_1 + a_0a_1a_2$

...

So in general, it seems that $\prod_{i = 0}^\infty (1+a_i) = 1 + \sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i + \text{cross terms} + \prod_{i = 0}^\infty a_i$. However $\prod_{i = 0}^\infty a_i$ blows up so I cannot see how it is bounded.

Does anyone see how to proceed from here?

Comment: Note that (if $a_i\geq 0$) $\prod_{i}(1+a_i)<+\infty$ iff $\sum_{i}\ln(1+a_i)<+\infty$. What can you say about $\sum_{i}\ln(1+a_i)$ and $\sum_{i}a_i$?

Comment: Hint: $1+a \le e^a$

Comment: Hint: What standard function defined on positive numbers do you recall that takes multiplication to addition? And what properties do you recall of it?

Comment: $\prod_{i = 0}^\infty a_i$ doesn't blow up; it is zero. But that's irrelevant here, because @achillehui's hint tells you all you need to know.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria).

Comment: This has been answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622278/relation-between-the-convergence-of-sum-a-n-and-prod-1a-n) in this site.