# $\lim_{a \to \infty}\prod_{i=0}^{a} x_i = \infty$ for $x_i > 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, examples-counterexamples, infinite-product

For $x_i > 1$, where $i$ is an index and $x_i$ real number, $\lim_{a \to \infty}\prod_{i=0}^{a} x_i = \infty$ always? How does one prove/disprove this?

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 6 questions during your fist two days on the site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: And if I might add another advice, I think that registering on the site might be useful. I have seen many times situations where users with unregistered accounts lost access to their posts. And I also wanted to say: Welcome to math.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively easy to find a counterexample showing that this is not true. Simply choose any increasing bounded sequence $(p_n)$ such that $p_0=1$. I.e., you have $p_n<p_{n+1}$ for each $n$ and, since the sequence is bounded, there exists a finite limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} p_n=P$.

Now you can put $x_0=1$ and
$$x_n = \frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}$$
for $n>1$.

In this way you have
$$\prod_{k=0}^n x_k = p_n$$
and
$$\prod_{k=0}^\infty x_k = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=0}^n x_k = P.$$

Moreover, you have $x_k>1$ for each $k$.

---

It was already mentioned in another answer that there is a general criterion for convergence of infinite products of the form $\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1+a_k)$ (where $a_k$ is a real sequence). You will probably find several posts about this if you browse (or search) the [infinite-product](/questions/tagged/infinite-product) tag a bit. For example:

- [sufficiency and necessity of convergence of $\sum a_n$ wrt convergence of $\prod (1 + a_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380094/sufficiency-and-necessity-of-convergence-of-sum-a-n-wrt-convergence-of-prod)
- [$\prod (1+a_n)$ converges iff $ \sum a_n$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426670/prod-1a-n-converges-iff-sum-a-n-converges)
- [Suppose $a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649878/suppose-a-n0-for-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-prod-n-1-infty-1a-n-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you write $x_i=1+u_i>1$ then the product converges iff $\sum_i u_i <+\infty$. You may see this by taking log and make a comparison through Taylor